# Java does nothing with my jar - from VB.net

Tags: java, vb.net, minecraft

I made a project for launching a game (.jar file) and it doesn't work. I tried many things and finally; Java launched. No errors. But 1 problem. The game itself didn't launch, and I'm sure I used the right arguments because I would get an error.
Here's my code. I've got a CMD window popping up with the title "[path to java]\java.exe" and disappearing immediately.

```
    Dim process As New Process
    Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo
    info.FileName = GetJavaHome() + "\java.exe"
    info.CreateNoWindow = False
    info.UseShellExecute = False
    info.RedirectStandardError = False
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    '''' Dim args As String = "-jar ""{6}"" -datafolder{0} -natives{1} -lwjgl{2} -mlcfg{3} -mlmod{4} -j{5} -u{6} -s{7}"
    'Got error: Corrupt jar file... Someone with Minecraft Experience can help me to launch it?
    Dim args As String = "-jar ""{6}"" -datafolder ""{0}"" -natives ""{1}"" -lwjgl ""{2}"" -mlcfg ""{3}"" -mlmod ""{4}"" -j ""{6}"" -u ""{7}"" -s ""{8}"""
    ' Got CMD window popping up with error and disappearing
    info.Arguments = String.Format(args, Application.StartupPath, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\bin\natives\", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\bin\lwjgl.jar", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\config\", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\mods\", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\mods\", Application.StartupPath & "\bin\minecraft.jar", TextBox1.Text, result)
    'info.Arguments = info.Arguments.Replace("\bin\minecraft.jar", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\bin\minecraft.jar")
    process.StartInfo = info
    process.Start()
```

Now, the error is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
```

And I'm pretty sure I defined the LWJGL jar file with testing this:

```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Max Korlaar\Dropbox\Max & Alex\MineCraft Launcher\MineCraft Launcher\bin\Debug\bin\minecraft.jar" -lwjgl "C:\Users\Max Korlaar\Dropbox\Max & Alex\MineCraft Launcher\MineCraft Launcher\bin\Debug\bin\lwjgl.jar"
```

Comment: Java home usually returns something like this: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`, so you should append `\bin\java.exe`

Comment: That's not the problem; the java path is correct (I have a class for finding it, and adding the bin folder). Else java won't start (and disappear...) and I would get a file not found error

Comment: try to output the full command you execute and then run it manually from command line to see what is wrong

Comment: I've got the following error in CMD: The syntax of the filename, foldername or volumename is incorrect. (Translated from Dutch). I copied all my arguments, with java in front of it and pasted it in CMD. In the quick disappearing CMD window from my program I've got an different error (From the jar file, so in my program the syntaxt is correct, I guess)

Comment: Got something now, see my question for the code.

Comment: append following parameter to your command: `"path/to/java.exe" -classpath "path/to/LWJGL.jar" -jar "..." -lwjgl "..."`

Comment: Weird, I did that and still got the same error

Comment: then you should check that the path is correct and that the jar contains class `org/lwjgl/LWJGLException`

Answer (score 0):

A place you should check is [Launch Minecraft from command line - usename and password as prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix).
Example:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Djava.library.path=natives/ -cp "minecraft.jar;lwjgl.jar;lwjgl_util.jar" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft <username> <sessionID>
```