# Running minecraft using commandline with username and password

Tags: command-line, minecraft

I'm trying to make a custom launcher but i don't know how to launch minecraft using the command line. I have seen this question: [Launch Minecraft from command line - usename and password as prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix). But the answer just doesn't work so could anyone tell me how to launch minecraft using the command line with username and password as prefix

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this:

```
java -Xincgc -Xmx1024m -cp %appdata%\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl_util.jar;%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\jinput.jar -Djava.library.path=%appdata%\.minecraft\bin\natives\ net.minecraft.client.Minecraft {username} {sessionCode}
```

You can get the sessioncode like this (=your linked post):

```
https://login.minecraft.net?user=<username>&password=<password>&version=13
```

The sessioncode is the content of the page and in the POST value. I doubt that you can do this only in cmd/batch. With the current launcher you can just do:

```
Minecraft.exe -u=<username> -p=<password>
```

This solution will open the Minecraft launcher and fill the fields with the given data.

Hope this helps :)