# How to start minecraft 1.8.9 from Command Prompt (Windows)

Tags: minecraft

I came up with this command so far:

```
java -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.9\1.8.9-natives -cp C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username Stefan15ist --version, 1.8.9 --gameDir C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken --userProperties --userType legacy
```

but when i run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which command line? Java? cmd? another?

Comment: Command Prompt. (Windows)

Comment: Unfortunately, Minecraft requires a valid session token, sent with your login credentials to **https://login.minecraft.net** so sadly this can't be done in cmd without security warnings or a different scripting language. I know it can be done in C# and C++. CMD just doesn't have the ability to ping a webpage and collect the return data.

Comment: I'm not interested in logging in to the minecraft website, I want to be able to join an offline server in my localhost

Comment: @Arescet You can use an existing token if you already have it (and the token is put into the logs).

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531917/launch-minecraft-from-command-line-usename-and-password-as-prefix), [this](http://wiki.vg/Authentication#Login) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/180308/how-to-force-minecraft-to-play-offline) may explain things.

Sadly you'll have to either connect to their website or disable your internet/block the launcher from sending requests. 
Minecraft doesn't naturally support connecting offline while its connected to the internet. 
Both options are impossible for a language like CMD with the default launcher.

Comment: well then I made the impossible because it's working.

Comment: @Stefan Bostan mind adding it as an answer to your own question then?