# Forge steal session token

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm wondering how to get Minecraft session id with Forge mod. Normally in Minecraft you use `mc.session.getToken()` but in Forge it doesn't show up. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in this post's answers:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506263/how-to-get-a-minecarft-session-id#:~:text=You%20can%20manually%20crash%20your,will%20be%20your%20session%20id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506263/how-to-get-a-minecarft-session-id#:%7E:text=You%20can%20manually%20crash%20your,will%20be%20your%20session%20id).

The top answer shows:

```
Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();

mc.getSession().getToken();
```

Maybe this is a capitalization error?

Comment: Answering questions by copying-and-pasting an answer from another question is counterproductive; flag the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks @pppery