# Minecraft Session ID

Tags: macos, minecraft, sessionid

How do I get my minecraft session Id on mac? I have searched everywhere on google but I couldn't find anything. I am trying to launch minecraft from the command line.

I have tried googling and I expected that the result would turn up what I wanted, but I got this:

[My Google Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6m1.png)

I also looked here but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506263/how-to-get-a-minecraft-session-id) doesn't answer my question

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. It's hard to understand what you want. Which session ID you want? If it's connection one, you could not directly get it without beeing authenticated, and the link you gave already proposed 3 way to get it. if they are not answering, can you explain what's wrong, and [edit] your question to explain what's wrong with those answers?